# How to send real time data generated by Azure webjob to angular UI

Tags: python, angular, model-view-controller, signalr, azure-webjobs

I have a python script running continuously as a webjob on Azure. In almost every 3 minutes it generates a new set of data. Once the data is generated we want to send it to UI(angular) in real time.

What could be the ideal approach (fastest) to get this functionality?

The data generated is a json containing 50 key value pairs. I read about signalr, but can I directly use signalr with my python code? Is there any other approach like sockets etc.?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), this is a protocol which allows back-end servers to push data to connected web clients.

There are implementations of WebSocket for python (a quick search found me [this one](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/)).

Once you have a WebSocket going, you can create a service in o your angular project to handle the yields from your python service, most likely using observables.

Hopefully this sets you on the right path

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement it.